# selenium headless not functioning with buttons properly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I have some code to open a search url for a site, click the first result, and click a button. This all works fine until I try to use headless Chrome.

Code (working -> not using headless Chrome):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=chatgpt")
f=browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "h3")
f[0].click()
button = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
button[0].click()
print("Page title was '{}'".format(browser.title))
input()
```

Output (which is what I want):

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58358/devtools/browser/e8f33ba5-9423-4900-9d36-035615599b61
Page title was 'ChatGPT'
[6464:11928:0914/044721.426:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(225)] [04:47:21.426] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
```

Code (not working -> using headless Chrome):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=chatgpt")
f=browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "h3")
f[0].click()
button = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
button[0].click()
print("Page title was '{}'".format(browser.title))
input()
```

Error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58289/devtools/browser/e4c33772-2e8c-4060-96b6-6aa730ef53c2
[0914/044642.023:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'unload'.", source:  (0)
[0914/044644.747:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'unload'.", source:  (0)
[0914/044645.283:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'.", source:  (0)
[0914/044645.284:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0914/044645.435:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to execute script from 'https://chat.openai.com/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/alpha/invisible.js?ts=1694649600' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.", source: about:blank (0)
[0914/044646.033:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'.", source:  (0)
[0914/044646.033:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\RapidAPI\willitworkorwillittwerk.py", line 14, in <module>
    button[0].click()
    ~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried google, youtube, chatgpt, and tiktok. Most sites are giving me the same thing, but example.com worked for some reason.

This is my first time trying to use headless mode. I asked chatgpt and it said this isn't intended behavior, so if anyone has any information, that would be great.

I also tried undetected_chromedriver, which I might just use, but it gave similar errors.

Chrome Version: 117.0.5938.63
Webdriver Version: 117.0.5938.62
Selenium Version: 4.12.0
i added --headless==new it removed the cloudflare errors but im still getting the out of index error but when its not headless i dont get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the new headless mode to get the same results as normal mode:

```py
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

You'll see that if you search for `--headless=new` in the Selenium documentation on https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/

---

If you're still having issues, try [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) UC Mode after `pip install seleniumbase`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

try:
    driver = Driver(uc=True, headless2=True)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=chatgpt")
    driver.click("h3")
    driver.click("button")
    print(driver.title)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Here's the result after running with `python`:

```
ChatGPT
```

Comment: Okay so im not getting the cloudflare errors but im still getting the problem that headless isnt function the same when im not using it
 `
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65524/devtools/browser/c9775dee-14e3-4e86-a4b0-79c868e210c1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\RapidAPI\willitworkorwillittwerk.py", line 71, in <module>
    login_button[0].click()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
`

Comment: sorry for the late response**

Comment: I added a SeleniumBase version that gets around your issue.

Comment: thank you!! i finished integrating it into everything and it worked like a charm